# How we will get the joomla's configurations.php variables in custom php file?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to use the email settings in my custom php file. Email settings i am setting in Admin level means added in Global configuration. I found the all setting and variables in configuration.php file. $smtpuser and $smtppass variables need to use in custom file.I am using joomla 3.2.
Please help me, How i can use these configuration variables in my custom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to **create the object of the JConfig class**. Here is the code, that will explain briefly. *I've used db connection variables, you can use your variables instead of that.*

```
    require_once ('configuration.php' ); // since this file n configuration file both are at the same location

    $var_cls = new JConfig(); // object of the class

    // variables that you want to use 
    $smtpuser = $var_cls->smtpuser; 
    $smtppass = $var_cls->smtppass;

    // for db connectivity if you want  
    $connlink = mysql_connect($var_cls->host, $var_cls->user, $var_cls->password) or die("Connection Failure to Database");
    mysql_select_db($var_cls->db, $connlink);

 return $db_prefix = $var_cls->dbprefix; // db prefix
```

Comment: If your custom file and configuration file are at different location, then change your `require_once`  configuration file path

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$prefix = $db->getPrefix();
```

**OR**

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$prefix = $db->getPrefix();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It would be nice of you to provide some context and explanation for the code you pasted.